# Type feature is not available in select dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select dropdown with search option that displays dynamic data,its working fine,but i need to add one more feature like if the user types anything and it is not available in the option then he should be allowed to simply type and provide an input. it should not be like this that if the user's desired value is not in dropdown then he is not able to type also

The link that i am following for dropdown is [this](https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/149076/Bootstrap-DropDownList-with-Filter-Option-using-bootstrap-select-plugin-in-ASPNet/)

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />

 <select name="ddlCountry" id="Select1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search-style="begins" data-live-search="true">
    <?php foreach($location as $loc): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $loc->city.', '.$loc->state;?>" ><?php echo $loc->city.', '.$loc->state;?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Can anyone please give me any suggestions,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html5 datalist feature to achieve this functionality,

```
 <input name="ddlCountry" id="Select1" class="selectpicker" data-live-search-style="begins" data-live-search="true" >
<datalist id="Select1">
    <?php foreach($location as $loc): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $loc->city.', '.$loc->state;?>" ><?php echo $loc->city.', '.$loc->state;?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires you to capture the input as the user is typing, the other issue with the above solution, it is tricky to use select and options, instead, use input type text as in the below code.

The below code needs a bit of tweaking.

Html and PHP

```
<input list="select1" name="ddlCountry" class="selectpicker" data-live-search-style="begins" data-live-search="true" /><
<datalist id="select1">
<?php foreach($location as $loc): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $loc->city.', '.$loc->state;?>" ><?php echo $loc->city.', '.$loc->state;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</datalist>
```

Every time the user enters the data, we need a way to capture the new entry
AJAX and Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('keyup', 'input[name="ddlCountry"]', function() {
    alert($('input[name="ddlCountry"]').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "{PHP url}",
        method: "GET",
        data: {
          search: $('#Select1 option:selected').val()
        },
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        //assuming the data is returned as an array
        var tmp_variable = '';
        data.foreach(function(item) {
          tmp_variable = tmp_variable + '<option value="' + item + '">';
        })
        $('#select1').html(tmp_variable);
      });
  });
})
```